# Prove that $[f(x+1)-f(x)] = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know this is a very elementary level question. But, I still need t0 understand this in term of mean value theorem. So here it goes:

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and lim$_{x \to \infty} f'(x ) = 0$. Prove that lim$_{x \to \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)] = 0$.

Here, can we assume $f'(x ) = \frac{f(x+1) - f(x)}{(x+1) -x}$ and proceed to conclusion?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x+1)−f(x)]=0$?

Comment: [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem): $\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x} = f'(c)$ for some $c\in(x,x+1)$.

Comment: Its false. Let $f = \frac 1 x$

Answer (score 5):

For each $x>0$ there is a $c_x\in(x,x+1)$ with
$$ f'(c_x) = \frac{f(x+1) - f(x)}{(x+1) - x} = f(x+1) - f(x). $$
Now, $c_x > x$ tends to $\infty$ for $x\to\infty$, thus
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x+1) - f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(c_x) = 0. $$

Comment: Then, what  is $f'(x) = 0$ for?

Comment: There is a difference between $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = 0$ and $f'(x^*) = 0$ for some specific $x^*$. The first one means that the derivative comes arbitrarily near to zero when $x$ becomes arbitrarily large, it need not to be zero. Think like $f(x) = 1/x$.